# Creating a moving trees animation in adobe XD

Tags: adobe-xd

I'm new to XD and am just wanting to create an animation with with below. Basically I want to create illusion of movement so I would like the trees behind the truck to roll continuously as if the truck is driving past them I'm just not quite sure how to do it. I'm thinking potentially the trees have to be masked? and roll through that mask.

I've learnt about basic animation functions in XD through a tutorial Im following through with but the animation example is more going from one side of the page to the other.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a mask would work for this.  [see a very rough example](https://imgur.com/oE6tHNS).

Here's my set up

In artboard 1 the trees are grouped, and masked. Same in artboard 2, but I duplicated and moved the tree group by one tree to the left. Make sure both tree groups have the same identical name, or the animation won't work.

[image]

To get it to work, set an auto animate from artboard 1 to artboard 2, with the trigger set to time delay = 0s, easing = none, but when you link back to artboard 1 from artboard 2, set the Type = Transition, and set Animation = none, so it just flips back immediately to the first state. When you play the animation it should just continue forever.